# Export selected region of Unity tilemap to c# array?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a small region of the map selected with the "Select an area of the grid" tool from the tile palette.  I'd like to be able to copy-and-paste this area for usage elsewhere in a programmatic way.  Since the location this region will be placed is determined via scripts, it's not sufficient to just directly copy and place these tiles down elsewhere - I think they need to take the form of a c# array so I can read through that and then use it elsewhere when the time comes.  How can I achieve this?

[image]